# How to check if any item in object matches any key in other array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to see if any item in `arr2` matches any top level key from `arr1` (forms or assets).

First array:

```
const arr1 = {
  forms: {
    permissions: {
      create: true,
      edit: true,
      delete: true,
    },
  },
  assets: {
    permissions: {
      create: true,
      edit: true,
      delete: true,
    },
  },
};
```

Second array:

```
const arr2 = ["assets", "media"];
```

I have tried this:

```
if (arr2 in arr1) {
    console.log("key is in contained in object");
}
```

But this only works when there is only one item in `arr2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the array use [Array#some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) with a test using [Object#hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).

For objects, you don't need to enumerate the keys of the object (O(n)): you can perform a direct test for the presence of a key (O(1)).

```js
const o = {
  forms: {
    permissions: {
      create: true,
      edit: true,
      delete: true,
    },
  },
  assets: {
    permissions: {
      create: true,
      edit: true,
      delete: true,
    },
  },
}

const arr = ["assets", "media"]

console.log(arr.some((k) => o.hasOwnProperty(k))) // true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get an array of the object's top level keys and then check if any of them are included in the other array.

Like so:

```js
const arr1 = {
  forms: {
    permissions: {
      create: true,
      edit: true,
      delete: true,
    },
  },
  assets: {
    permissions: {
      create: true,
      edit: true,
      delete: true,
    },
  },
};

const arr2 = ["assets", "media"];

function hasSomeTopLevelKey(object, arrayOfKeys) {
   return Object.keys(object)
   .some(topLevelKey => arrayOfKeys.includes(topLevelKey));
}

const x = hasSomeTopLevelKey(arr1, arr2)
console.log(x)
```